# Is there any better way to access hundreds of different record in database?

Tags: mysql, select

I'm going to read records from database(MySQL) by name using this select statement:

```
select * from table where name = 'xxx'
```

But I have hundreds of names in one http request, so if I use the above statement, I have to issue hundreds of select. Or I just use MySQL `select .. in` to reduce sql calls.

But it's still too slow. So, any better approach to archieve my purpose? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Too slow? Make sure your database has a proper index for the `name` column, and let it do the hard work for you.

Comment: @jweyrich I mean I have to issue hundreds of sql in one http request processing, so whether I use a column that with index is not the key point.

Comment: Why haven't you tried the call with WHERE ... IN?

Comment: @Perception I tried as I said in my question. But when I join these names in one `where ... in`, it exceeded `in`'s max length. So I split the names into several `where ... in`, but it still not fit my need, I hope to retrieve all the information at once. I know cache the data in memory can do it, but I hope to find some way that doesn't need cache. If there's no way to do it, I will fall back to `where ... in`

Comment: According to the MySQL documentation there is no explicit limit for the number of values you can put in the IN statement other then the DB-Level "max_allowed_packet" setting. Are you getting a "Packet too large" error?

Can you give us more details on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Martin index *is* the point. If you don't have an index on *name* MySQL has to go through the whole table to find your names, it's `O(n*m)` n rows, m names. With an index it's more likely to be `O(log(n)*m)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st thing you should have index on 'name' if you are using in where condition. And if you have more conditions in where try to figure out more which more columns can have indexes.

2nd thing use IN query it will solve minimize your database calls.

```
select * from table where name IN ( 'xxx', 'syz', 'abc',....);
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to me that there's no better way around.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you divide total names in chunks and then use those chunks in select statements, your issue will be fixed. lets say

```
$names = array($n1,$n2...);
$totalnames = count($totalnames);
$chunksize = 50;   
$totalChunks = ceil($totalnames/$chunksize);
for($i=0;$i<$totalChunks;$i++)
{
  $j = $chunksize*$i;
  for($k=$j;$k<=$j;$k++)
  {
    select statement with in
   }
}
```